# Starting rails server always throws socket error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Nine times out of ten, whenever I start either the default rails webrick server, or thin server, I get a socket error. I have to do `lsof | grep IPv4`, find the ruby process, then `kill -9` the PID. It seems like I'm doing this all the time... is there not a permanent solution to this? Is it b/c I sometimes close the terminal window without control+C'ing the server instance?

Comment: Can you post the specific error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is probably because you are not killing the server instance.  By default, the server listens on `localhost:3000`, so if the process is still alive after you quit your terminal, it is still occupying the port, and attempting to start another server will fail.  Just control-c your servers before you close the terminal session and you shouldn't have any more issues.

Comment: Figured as much. I was hoping there was a config that would kill instances when the terminal died, but alas... control+C it is!

Answer (score 0):

Aso if you can use rails s -p x     .In this x is port no 3000 or 3001 etc.you will not get any bind error if ctrl + c is not pressed to close the server.Also it's better to use ctrl + c to close the server